# New to SQL Oracle. Increasing data in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

So I I currently have the sql statement to find the desired salarys but now I just need to manipulate the salaries so I can increase them before it is outputted to the screen

```
SELECT employee_id AS "Employee Number",
       SUBSTR(CONCAT(CONCAT(last_name, ','), first_name),1,25) AS "Full Name",
       job_id AS "Job",
       salary
FROM employees
WHERE (job_id LIKE '%VP%'
       OR job_id LIKE '%MAN%'
       OR job_id LIKE '%MGR%')
  AND (salary > 11000
       OR salary < 6000)
ORDER BY salary DESC
```

now what i want to do is depending on the job_id i want to increase the salary by 30 or 20%. I have no clue how i go about doing it but I am assuming I use CASE or ROUND. Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Do you want to permanently _update_ the data in the table? Or just change the _display_ but leave the data in the table unchanged?

Answer (score -1):

Use case! you are right

```
SELECT  employee_id AS "Employee Number",SUBSTR(CONCAT(CONCAT(last_name, ','), first_name),1,25) AS "Full Name"
      , CASE WHEN (job_id like '%VP%' or job_id like '%MAN%'or job_id like '%MGR%') AND (salary > 11000 or     salary < 6000) THEN salary * 1.2
        ELSE salary
        END
  FROM employees
```

not tested..

Comment: You may want to test if before you write your answer.

Comment: I attempted to use case but now SQL is giving me an error saying its expecting the from statement earlier

Comment: Sorry I don't have oracle on this computer, may the error occur because of "JOB_ID like" (after WHEN) so, Try test after delete that term. thanks.